# How do I solve the equation $e^{\ln(2x+1)} = 5x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

The problem is 
$$e^{\ln(2x+1)}    =5x$$

I've tried using natural logs to both sides like..
$2x+1= \ln 5x $
But I'm not sure if $\ln$ and $e^{\ln}$ cancel out.

Comment: $e^{\ln(f(x))} = f(x)$.

Comment: Why (trigonometry) tag?

Comment: Hello welcome to math.stackexchange. This is actually a well-posed question. It is always a good habit to tell what you have tried, it is actually something that we like. Keep up those good quality questions. Question upvoted!

Comment: If you apply the natural log to both sides, you get $\log(2x+1)=\log(5x)$

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the exponential and the logarithm are inverses: $$e^{\ln(\color{red}{\rm stuff})} = \color{red}{\rm stuff}, \quad \ln(e^{\color{blue}{\rm stuff}}) = \color{blue}{\rm stuff},$$ so that $e^{\ln(2x+1)} = 2x+1$.

Comment: For $\color{red}{\text{stuff}} > 0$

Comment: $\ln(e^{stuff}) = stuff + 2i \pi k$, where $k$ depends on  which branch has been chosen for the $\ln$

Answer (score 4):

e raised to the power of a natural log cancels out both. This just leaves you with $2x+1=5x,$ or $x=\frac{1}{3}$

Answer (score 2):

The logarithm is the inverse of the exponential, meaning $exp \circ log = id$.

It then follows that $e^{log(2x+1)}=2x+1=5x$ which should be easy to solve.

Answer (score 1):

$e^{ln(x)}$ $=$x

check the following pdf for this and more properties of logs

http://assets.wne.edu/95/exps_and_logs.pdf

Using this property we can see that

$2x+1$ = $5x$

$x$ $=$ ${1/3}$

Answer (score 1):

If you apply natural log to both sides, you should instead get$$\begin{align*}
\ln\left[e^{\ln(2x+1)}\right] &= \ln(5x)\\
\ln(2x+1)\cdot\ln(e) &= \ln(5x)\\
\ln(2x+1)\cdot1 &= \ln(5x)\\
\ln(2x+1) &= \ln(5x)\\
&\vdots
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

$e^{\ln a}=a$, for $a\gt-1/2$. so $2x+1=5x$ and solve for $x$.

Comment: Well... Aren't you missing the condition $x>-\frac12$ ?

Comment: Yes sorry forgot that

Answer (score 1):

Because $e^x$ and $\ln x$ both have domains $x > 0$ where they are injective then, given that they are inverses of one another means that the composition of them yields the identity function. Specifically we have $$\ln e^x = e^{\ln x} =x$$

The same logic applies to other functions, for example, consider the function $x^3$ and the function $x^{1/3}$, they are inverses of another. The cube function is the inverse of the cube root function and vice-versa. So composing them yields the identity again $$(x^3)^{1/3} = (x^{1/3})^3 = x $$

Another example would be, considering a suitable domain for $x$, that $$\arcsin \sin x = \sin \arcsin x = x$$

The list of example goes on... and I hope I've provided a valuable insight into your understanding of how composing inverses yields the identity.